# Android: Display HTML formatted text in a ListView when loaded from database

Tags: android, html, sqlite, textview

I have an SQLite database of items where some of them contain basic HTML such as b and sub tags. I've bound the table to a ListView using a SimpleCursorAdapter. Is there a way to make the ListView format the HTML tags so it displays properly? 
It seems like the way forward is to get the Cursor to deliver SpannedStrings but I can't work out how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Ian, this is my final adapter code:

```
    private class HtmlCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public HtmlCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewText (TextView view, String text) {
        view.setText(Html.fromHtml(text),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Since that constructor is now deprecated in `SimpleCursorAdapter`, I changed the signature to `public HtmlCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)` and the `super` call to `super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);`

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains only simple HTML tags, they can actually be handled by a TextView by using Html.fromHtml(yourString).  That static method returns a Spanned, which can be displayed by a TextView with far less overhead than a WebView.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know where I can put this code. I tried extending TextView but the setText method is set as final.

Comment: You don't need to extend TextView, just pass it the Spanned returned by Html.fromHtml() rather than the String from the Cursor.  You can extend the SimpleCursorAdapter and override the setViewText method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CursorWrapper class.

```
CursorWrapper cw = new CursorWrapper(myCursor) {
    public String getString(int columnIndex) {
        String withHTML = super.getString(columnIndex);
        return Html.fromHtml(withHTML).toString();
    }
};
```